# Killing a process started using system()

Tags: linux, perl

1. How to kill time-taking process or stuck process (generated through
   `system` command) using Perl.
2. How to kill a process that was started using the `system` command taking too much time or stuck some where.

Comment: What's the difference between the two questions?

Answer (score 2):

If you are expecting to kill the process called by system() inside the same script, there's no way to get its PID or kill it, since the system() call wouldn't return until the process is done. Instead you can use fork() to create a new process, and execute your process originally called by system() in the new created process by exec(). The fork() will return the PID of child process, then you can kill it with kill() whenever you want.

http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/fork.html

http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/exec.html

http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/kill.html

Answer (score 2):

Section 8 of the Perl FAQ contains

> #### [How do I timeout a slow event?](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq8.html#How-do-I-timeout-a-slow-event?)
>
> Use the [`alarm`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/alarm.html) function, probably in conjunction with a signal handler, as documented in [Signals in perlipc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlipc.html#Signals) and the section on “Signals” in the Camel. You may instead use the more flexible [Sys::AlarmCall](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Sys%3A%3AAlarmCall) module available from CPAN.
>
> The [`alarm`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/alarm.html) function is not implemented on all versions of Windows. Check the documentation for your specific version of Perl.

The [“Signals” section of the perlipc documentation](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlipc.html#Signals) contains

> Signal handling is also used for timeouts in Unix. While safely protected within an [`eval{}`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/eval.html) block, you set a signal handler to trap alarm signals and then schedule to have one delivered to you in some number of seconds. Then try your blocking operation, clearing the alarm when it’s done but not before you've exited your [`eval{}`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/eval.html) block. If it goes off, you'll use [`die`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/die.html) to jump out of the block.
>
> Here's an example:
>
> ```
> my $ALARM_EXCEPTION = "alarm clock restart";
> eval {
>     local $SIG{ALRM} = sub { die $ALARM_EXCEPTION };
>     alarm 10;
>     flock(FH, 2)    # blocking write lock
>                     || die "cannot flock: $!";
>     alarm 0;
> };
> if ($@ && $@ !~ quotemeta($ALARM_EXCEPTION)) { die }
> ```
>
> If the operation being timed out is [`system`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/system.html) or [`qx`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#qx%2fSTRING%2f), this technique is liable to generate zombies. If this matters to you, you'll need to do your own [`fork`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/fork.html) and [`exec`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/exec.html), and kill the errant child process.
>
> For more complex signal handling, you might see the standard [POSIX](http://perldoc.perl.org/POSIX.html) module. Lamentably, this is almost entirely undocumented, but the [`t/lib/posix.t`](http://perl5.git.perl.org/perl.git/blob/9a9cbd715960a905dcbc9166349a73a64a007e4e:/ext/POSIX/t/posix.t) file from the Perl source distribution has some examples in it.

Answer (score 0):

It is advisable to use fork and exec, mainly as a security precaution (user input).

However if you are not concerned about user input and are aware of the process you have started using system, then you could open a pipe to the tasklist or ls calls, process them with grep to find the process you are bothered about then send kill signals to those processes.